# unbound method __init__() error in unit tests but not in regular executions

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, inheritance

I got this:

```
        DataBaseStorage.__init__(
>         self, key=key, sz=sz,
        )
E       TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with DataBaseStorage instance as first argument (got BaseStorage instance instead)

path/to/file/DataBase.py:80: TypeError
```

The traceback is a bit scattered, but right above this error, the call is:

```
# This is referring to a call to DerivedStorage.__init__
path/to/file/Base.py:213: in __init__
```

in a unit test. I haven't run across this error in non-unit test executions even though those executions go down the same path, so I am not sure what is going on.

The inheritance hierarchy here is poorly designed (unfortunately we can't change it currently), but it looks like below (skeleton code):

```
class DerivedStorage(DataBaseStorage):
  def __init__(self, key, sz):
    # do some stuff
    DataBaseStorage.__init__(self, key, sz)

class BaseStorage(DerivedStorage):
  def __init__(self, key, sz):
    # do some stuff
    DerivedStorage.__init__(self, key=key, sz=sz)
    # do some other stuff
```

Also note that we have to support python2 in the codebase.

I've found several similar questions with issue, but I don't think they answer the question because this code does work outside of unit tests, but in unit tests it fails. What could be causing that?

The unit test itself crashes on the following line:

```
  bsto = BaseStorage(
    key=key,
    sz=10,
  )
```

edit: I mentioned that it works in non-unit-test executions, and I think that's because we've been using python3+ for those executions, so I think this issue may be specific to python 2.7.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana Give me a few minutes. This was the output of the a continuous integration test, and the traceback seems a bit scattered. I need dto consolidate it

Comment: Does `DataBaseStorage` inherit from `object`? And can you use `super()` (in its Python 2.7 form)?

Comment: Which code creates a `BaseStorage` instance that is not a unit test? Since you mention that that works.

Comment: The error is what is says: `__init__` of `DataBaseStorage` is called, but `self` in that call is a `BaseStorage` instance, which is not what `__init__` expects.

Comment: @9769953 I don't think so, but how would `object` affect this? Does `super()` solve the issue here? I also edited the OP, it appears this is a python2.7 specific issue and the non-unit-test executions were all done in python3

Comment: "the non-unit-test executions were all done in python3": yes, that may change things. I can't even recall exactly, but inheriting ultimately from `object` in Python 2 may make a notable difference (though it may only have to do when `super()` is used). In Python 3, every class automatically inherits from `object`, and that seems to work...

Comment: Have you run the unit tests with Python 3?

Comment: @9769953 I didn't see any failures with python3 unit tests, so presumably they passed. I can try `super()` and see if that works

Comment: I think it might be the `object` inheritance. But try [`super(<class>, self)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#super) in its Python 2.7 form as well.

Comment: You mention: "unfortunately we can't change it currently". Do you mean the design, or the actual code?

Comment: @9769953 Ok, so I just tried to run the non-unit-test executions with `python2.7` and I'm having the same issue, so I think it is indeed associated with python2.7. We can't change the design (I personally hate it. it's so messy)

Comment: @9769953 Tried `super` and it gives a similar error `super(DataBaseStorage, self).__init__(
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. I wonder why python3.7 allows this but not python2?

Comment: As I mentioned before: make sure your classes inherit from `object`. Apparently, you can change the code (just not the overall structure), so trace back the origin of `DataBaseStorage` and make sure the ultimate parent inherits from `object`. Do keep the `super(...)` calls around asa well.

Comment: `super(type, obj): ` that can't be right: `type` is incorrect, it should be class name, not `type`. And `obj` should be `self`. I provided a link to the relevant documentation: did you read that.

Comment: @9769953 Oh sorry didn't see it was a hyperlink. just read it, but I think my usage is correct. `DataBaseStorage` is the class name, which is a `type`. it's saying that the `self` that's passed in isn't an instance of `DataBaseStorage`

Comment: Ok, do what you want, but I think it's wrong.

Comment: @9769953 uh how is it wrong? it's literally using the class name which is exactly what you said above. i think you misread the error

Comment: In your super call, `type` is not a class name, and `obj` is not `self`.

Comment: @9769953 reread the comment `super(DataBaseStorage, self).__init__()` is the call. `super(type, obj)` is the description of the error....

Comment: Ok; did you inherit ultimately from `object` as well? You'll need both the super and the object part.