# unbound method __init__() error with python2 but not with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, inheritance

This is related to my earlier question: [unbound method __init__() error in unit tests but not in regular executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324839/unbound-method-init-error-in-unit-tests-but-not-in-regular-executions?noredirect=1#comment134593579_76324839)

I made a minimal reproducible example below:

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self):
    print("base constructor")

class derived(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    print("derived constructor")

class Secondary(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    derived.__init__(self)

s = Secondary()
```

If you run this with `python3.7` (or any python3 version I think), it works fine, but with `python2.7`, you get the error

```
$ python2.7 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    s = Secondary()
  File "test.py", line 11, in __init__
    derived.__init__(self)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with derived instance as first argument (got Secondary instance instead)
```

Why does this work with python3 but not python2? Is there a way to make this work with python2?

Also tried using `super` (had to make `Base` inherit `object` to use it):

```
class Base(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print("base constructor")

class derived(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    print("derived constructor")

class Secondary(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super(derived, self).__init__()

s = Secondary()
```

There's still an issue with `python2`. The error changes (similar meaning I think):

```
$ python2.7 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    s = Secondary()
  File "test.py", line 11, in __init__
    super(derived, self).__init__()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: what about `super().__init__()` ?

Comment: @azro Will update OP (it gives a similar error)

Comment: @azro Wait, actually isn't `super` meant to be used with parent class constructors?

Comment: Python 3 changed how `function.__get__` works when the function is accessed from a class: it returns the underlying function, instead of an instance of `method` lacking a reference to the invoking object.

Comment: `Secondary` should *not* be trying to call `derived.__init__` in the first place, as it doesn't inherit from `derived`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I agree. Unfortunately, I've been trying to get my team to change the entire design and it's in the plan for the near future hopefully.

Comment: Until you fix the design, I wouldn't use `super` with `Secondary`. Passing `derived` only tells `super` where to start looking in the MRO of `self`. An instance of `Secondary` won't *have* `derived` in its MRO at all.

Comment: @chepner Is there a hacky way to make it work with python2 without super?

Comment: Try `derived.__init__.im_func(self)`, which calls the function wrapped by the `instancemethod` rather than the `instancemethod` itself. (If you want code that works in Python 2 and Python 3, you'll need to use an `if` statement that checks which version of Python you are using in order to determine which thing to call.)

Comment: @chepner This is getting really ugly. We really need to change this

Comment: An important factor here is that `Base` doesn't derive from `object`. This makes all those "old-style" classes in Python 2.  They behave slightly differently from classes in Python 3, where if you don't specify a base class, it derives from `object` by default.

Comment: @kindall True, but I don't think it makes a difference here.

Comment: (By which I mean, `function` is a new-style class, and so can trigger the descriptor protocol whether or not the class having `function`-valued attributes is old- or new-style.)

Comment: @chepner I tried using `derived.__init__.im_func(self)` but am getting the same error as in the OP

Comment: If I use that line in `Secondary.__init__`, I get `derived constructor` as the output. (I get an `AttributeError` in Python 3, of course.) Did you *replace* the call to `derived.__init__`, or just add the call to `derived.__init__.im_func` after it?

Comment: @chepner Oh you're right. I tried it in my actual code and not in the minimal example above. So there must be another issue. In my actual code, when I printed the `type(Secondary.__init__.im_func)`, I am seeing `<type 'function'>`. is this what it should be?

Comment: Yes; it's the actual `function` object bound to the attribute `__init__`, rather than the result of calling `derived.__dict__['__init__'].__get__`. (See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html for more information about how the descriptor protocol works.)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, accessing a `function`-valued class attribute always produces an instance of `instancemethod`, whether you access it via the class or an instance of the class.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     pass
...
>>> type(Foo.__init__)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> type(Foo().__init__)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

The only difference is whether the `instancemethod` has a reference to an object that can be passed to the function when you call the `instancemethod`.

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> Foo.__init__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> Foo.__init__(f)  # OK
>>> f.__init__()  # OK
```

In Python 3, accessing a `function`-valued class attribute on a class produces the raw function; only when you access it via an instance of the class do you get an instance of `method`.

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self):
...     pass
...
>>> type(Foo.__init__)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(Foo().__init__)
<class 'method'>
```